# ExtJs4 + IE9 = Object doesn't support property or method 'createContextualFragment'

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-9

I'm working with ExtJs on IE9.. and i almost always get this error..

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>
> Object doesn't support property or
>   method 'createContextualFragment'

**What dose it means? What 'createContextualFragment' is needed for? And how to fix this?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`createContextualFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.createContextualFragment) is a method of `Range` objects that creates a document fragment from an HTML string. It's present in Firefox and WebKit and Opera but is currently non-standard (it's not in the [DOM Level 2 Range spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) but is in the work-in-progress [DOM Parsing and Serialization spec](http://html5.org/specs/dom-parsing.html#dom-range-createcontextualfragment)) and IE 9 didn't implement it, which is consistent with Microsoft's general approach to implementing standard functionality in IE 9 that was previously missing in IE. ExtJs must be using this method, although rather foolishly since it is non-standard and the same result can easily be achieved using `innerHTML`, which is supported everywhere.

**UPDATE**

You can patch the following into IE 9 since it allows extension of host object prototypes, which previous versions did not. The following is a naive implementation of `createContextualFragment()` adapted from my [Rangy library](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) but is suitable for most uses. See [this Rangy issue](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/issues/detail?id=67) for details and for a more thorough implementation.

Note that this will not work in IE < 9 because those browsers have no DOM Range implementation.

```
if (typeof Range.prototype.createContextualFragment == "undefined") {
    Range.prototype.createContextualFragment = function(html) {
        var startNode = this.startContainer;
        var doc = startNode.nodeType == 9 ? startNode : startNode.ownerDocument;
        var container = doc.createElement("div");
        container.innerHTML = html;
        var frag = doc.createDocumentFragment(), n;
        while ( (n = container.firstChild) ) {
            frag.appendChild(n);
        }
        return frag;
    };
}
```

Comment: can i somehow.. 'emulate' this method to make ExtJs work with IE9 (i don't like IE8 emulation mode)?

Comment: @tim-down Downvoter is http://stackoverflow.com/users/135952/nissan-fan.. he have some 'grudge' againts me, and he downvote some of my questions\answers.. sorry for involving you into this..

Comment: @Ai_boy: No problem. I just didn't think I'd said anything inaccurate or even provocative (which I do sometimes), so I was a bit surprised :)

Comment: For me, this patch caused problem in IE8, which apparently lacks the Range object altogether.  So I changed the conditional to
if (typeof Range != "undefined" && 
    typeof Range.prototype.createContextualFragment == "undefined")

Comment: @Jim: Yes, this answer makes no attempt to deal with IE version prior to version 9. If you need Range support in IE < 9, you can use Rangy (http://code.google.com/p/rangy/).

Comment: The code above does not work in IE9. Getting the document seams to fail.

Comment: @xotix: You're right, there was a bug. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Pasting the fix into ext-all gives me a `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'createElement'` error on the `var container` line. Fwiw.

Comment: These solutions have stopped working since some update... now it has a problem with 'Range' not existing as well. The best thing for those of us who can't update ExtJS to do is the X-UA-Compatible metatag.

Comment: We implemented this solution and it was working, but in a recent Windows update it seems to have broken it...

Comment: @RiverC: It will fail in IE9 Compatibility View, which (like older versions of IE) has no Range support. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I think so. So you'd need to force it into IE9 Strict mode then?

Comment: @RiverC: Yes, I think so. I'm not an expert in IE modes but it seems this is possible: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonbox/archive/2011/03/27/removing-the-ie9-compatibility-button-and-html1115-warning.aspx

Comment: This resolved the situation for me - what was weird was that this issue only occurred (for me) for a new installation of IE9 - a downgrade from IE10 to IE9 to try and reproduce this issue, continued to work as in IE10 - however a new install did exhibit the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Faster, tighter, no looping, works in IE9+ and all non-shit browsers:

```
var createContextualFragment = (function(){
  var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(''),
      range = doc.createRange(),
      body = doc.body;
  return function(html){
    body.innerHTML = html;
    range.selectNodeContents(body);
    return range.extractContents();
  }
})();
```

Comment: @TimDown check out this new hotness: it's smaller, less complex, and has better perf than the other answers.

Comment: Works in IE 10 with one change: pass in an empty string into `createHTMLDocument()`. I don't have IE 9 to hand.

Answer (score 2):

Well, with a small change, the code posted by Tim Down worked for me :

```
if (typeof Range.prototype.createContextualFragment == "undefined") {
    Range.prototype.createContextualFragment = function (html) {
        var doc = window.document;
        var container = doc.createElement("div");
        container.innerHTML = html;
        var frag = doc.createDocumentFragment(), n;
        while ((n = container.firstChild)) {
            frag.appendChild(n);
        }
        return frag;
    };
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you changed and the error in my code (which had `range` where I needed `this`). I've fixed my example now, which has the advantage over yours that it will work with Ranges from documents other than the current one (useful when working with iframes, for example).

Answer (score 2):

extjs 3.4.0 fixes this issue. No need to change the code bade. Good work on the library, though.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been fixed in Ext JS 3.3 IIRC, and I imagine it will be fixed in 4.0 prior to the final release (it hasn't even hit beta as of this writing).

Answer (score 1):

I've just applied Tim Down's fix to our ext 3.3.1 installation, because IE9 still doesn't display our pages correctly without it. In other words, I don't think this fix got into EXTJS 3.3, at least not the public version.

Comment: Just put this in the HTML header section `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`, so there will be no problem with IE9 :) Really, one line of 'html' code and your app will be working just fine with IE9