# Object doesn't support property or method 'createContextualFragment'

Tags: javascript, frame, doctype

A coworker is using Ipipeline to display some data in a frame. I need the same functionality and cloned much of that code.  The original pgm uses master pages in a CS.net environment while I am coding in a VB.net environment which uses user controls, not master pages.

If I View the HTM in the Browser in isolation, the page displays and the dropdown lists work perfectly. But when I embed it in an iframe tag in a very simple page and run, the page displays but then I get:

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'createContextualFragment'**  when clicking on the first drop-down list on the page.

This test page looks like:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <iframe id="frame1" src="../Ipipeline/xxxxx.htm"></iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I did see the StackOverflow article at
[StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375616/extjs4-ie9-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-createcontextualfragme)   but I don't think it pertains as this does work on my IE9 machine without the iframe.

Steps I have taken:

- I saw that the default DOCTYPE didn't allow for framesets so I exchanged it for one that does, but that didn't help: same behavior.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try Tim Down's patch from the question you link to? If not, do so.

Comment: The answer was to change `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`   But thank you for responding.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and adding this javascript to my page fixed the problem.
In my case it was related to an activewidget component calling createContextualFragment. I declared this javascript after all other javascript links and it solve the issue for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ((typeof Range !== "undefined") && !Range.prototype.createContextualFragment)
{
    Range.prototype.createContextualFragment = function(html)
    {
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), 
        div = document.createElement("div");
        frag.appendChild(div);
        div.outerHTML = html;
        return frag;
    };  
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Fede